# How do I display this spreadsheet (in the image) in a readable format to assess what values are increasing over batches

Tags: dataset

[image: Spreadsheet1]

How do I display this spreadsheet (in the image) in a readable format to assess what values are increasing over batches. The values relate to the frequency of alarms.  In the image the "property" column has 236 rows and the columns will be 150.

Comment: Welcome to CrossValidated.  Sometimes a question requires 2 or 3 phrasings to be really clear.  For me, a stumbling block is "over batches":  what do you mean by "batch" in this context?  Also, are you looking to rearrange the spreadsheet or to create one or more graphs based on it?

Comment: Hi Rolando, sorry beginners mistake! "batches" is just the column name, First Column is "Property" and every subsequent column (approx 150) will have a numerical title which is the "batch" I was talking about. I am looking to create graphs so its easy to see if the alarms have increased over these numerical headers or "batches". the first batch number may have been in February say and the last in March. I am tryingto see if maybe something wasnt alarming in February and has started now in late march. I hope this makes a little more sense!

Answer (score 0):

With 236 lines to evaluate in a line chart, even if only, say, 80 appear to be increasing according to whatever criteria you develop, you'd still have too many to be comfortably manageable. You'd have to put in a lot of work identifying those 80 properties by visual means and then listing them and perhaps sorting by or otherwise selecting them for further analysis.

More workable than such a graphical method would be a strictly numerical one. First, develop your criteria for what constitutes an increase.  This might mean a positive difference between last and first batch, but such a method would be pretty simplistic and would fail to take into account 148/150ths of the data.  Instead you could compute a regression slope characterizing each property, and you could mark as "increasing" those with slopes that are above some positive threshold.  You also might exclude from this list those that in regression have a sufficient quadratic effect, if this suits your purposes. Such an analysis would be straightforward in R and possibly in Stata; less so, I believe, in SPSS or SAS.

If you are limited to Excel, you could compute each row's correlation between columns 2 through 151 (the values for all the batches) and a row containing the constant values, 2 through 151.  Then any resulting correlations that fall above some threshold would signal row increases.